# Air Filter made car quiter

Tags: air-filter

Civic coupe vti 99.

Just removed the old man filter which had dirt and debris etc for another cheap £6 filter and the car got quiter.

I’m just wondering if the quietness be because the new filter isn’t blocked by dirt like the used one or is it because the new filter is different - besides it being cheap I noticed the intake side of the filter the depth is maybe 3 times more than the last one so would this be the cause?

I prefer louder.

Answer (score -1):

The car got quiter because the cheap new filter is cheap.. It has a lower porosity, therefor less air. As a remedy you could drill a few holes in the exhaust, it costs nothing and the car will get louder

Comment: Surely it would be better to replace the filter and get more air with economic and performance benefits than to drill holes in the exhaust and keep the cheap filter??!!

Comment: I would hope Joe was just kidding, but any leaks, including drilled holes, in the exhaust could leak carbon monoxide into the car.